# Queueing multiple GPUs using Jenkins and nvidia-docker

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nvidia-docker

I'm running Jenkins on a machine with 4 GPUs and run Jenkins jobs using `nvidia-docker` to use the GPUs. There is a `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` property that I can pass to `nvidia-docker` that let's me specify which GPUs are accessible in the container. What I'd like to do is to use Jenkins for managing GPU resources and queueing jobs accordingly, i.e. make parameterised jobs that ask user how many GPUs they need for the job and it can queue and start the job when they become available. Ideally I'd like to do this over multiple slave nodes where for instance each node has 4 GPUs.

Does this seem possible?

Answer (score 1):

The [`lock`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/) step should bring you a bit further. It provides couple of options to create and use/lock access to resources shared among couple of builds.

Please note that the job will be stated and then blocked during execution (so don't place the `lock` inside a `node` allocation).